# Find IP address of another computer using Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip, lan

I've connected my Linux PC to another Linux PC through LAN. Is there any way to find out the IP address of that computer without logging into it?

I've set my ip manually 192.168.7.12 and I don't know the ip range of that computer.

Answer (score 3):

### If you know the hostname of the Linux PC

From the **terminal** window, type the following command followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. (Where **hostname** is replaced with the hostname of the computer.

```
ping hostname
```

### If you don't know the hostname of the Linux PC

1. Install arp-scan by typing the following command in a **terminal** window followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   ```
    sudo apt-get install arp-scan
   ```

   **NOTE**: This may differ depending on the linux distribution.
2. Type the following command, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
    sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet
   ```

   **NOTE**: The interface may vary depending on your setup.
3. You will be given a list of IP addresses on your local network as well as the MAC address and vendor details.

Source: [Arp-scan User Guide (subheading Discovering all hosts on the local network)](http://www.nta-monitor.com/wiki/index.php/Arp-scan_User_Guide#Discovering_all_hosts_on_the_local_network)

Comment: thanks, but what if i don't know the range of ip of that computer? e.g if my ip is 192.168.7.12 but it maybe 42.10.0.1 or any other things?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that _arp-scan_ will detect all hosts on the local network. Have you used the command and was it unsuccessful?

Answer (score 0):

if that's wlan connection,try one of these following commands `ip monitor`;`wpa_cli -i (wlan interface name here) status`;`arp`.If that's adhoc,you can also use wpa_cli but use interface p2p instead of wlan,it's usually named as wlan0,p2p,wlan1,wlp2s0 or p2p-dev-wlp2s0.